# I know of two ways to define the finite number type. Is there words to distinguish between the two?

Tags: coq, dependent-type

I know of two ways to define the finite number type:

```
(* The conditions are described in the type definition. *)
Inductive fin (n : nat) :=
  | O_fin : fin (S O)
  | S_fin : forall n : nat, fin n -> fin (S n).

(* The conditions are defined by an outer predicate. *)
Definition fin (n : nat) := { x : nat | x < n }.
```

Are there two words to distinguish between the two? For example, the first method is called A and the second method is called B. I thought I had it memorized, but I forgot and it's hard to search.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what your question is?  'Are there "words"...'?  They are isomorphic, but different types, one has two constructors, and the other one just one.  The second one takes a propositional argument, and the first one takes a `nat`.

Comment: I added a more general explanation. Thank you.

Comment: I thought maybe intrinsic vs extrinsic? Not sure, I can't find a good reference.

Comment: I may have to create my own documentation. Anyway, thank you for sharing the information.